# CTreeCtrl - getting an item position

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a way of getting the position (index) of an item in a CTreeCtrl?
I am interested in the index of a node at its particular level.

I was thinking to maintain the item positions within the item "data" field, but the problem is that my tree is sorted and I cannot predict the position an item will receive (well, only if I sort the items in advance which I would like to avoid).

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow use the [GetMessagePos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938(v=vs.85).aspx) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. I assumed that maybe the control could be treated as an array (maybe it still can but I can't find a reference).

Anyways, there are no member functions (according to the [MFC API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w95665f(VS.80).aspx)) that give you access to that information

Comment: Can you think of a way of bypassing this issue? I was thinking to maintain the item positions within the item "data" field, but the problem is that my tree is sorted and I cannot predict the position an item will receive.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /// there is another way if you "Use Unicode Character Set" (visual studio)
 /// Properties->General->Character Set

    CPoint point;
    GetCursorPos(&point);
    m_Tree.ScreenToClient(&point);
    UINT nHitFlags;
    HTREEITEM hItem = m_Tree.HitTest(point, &nHitFlags);

    int idx = m_Tree.MapItemToAccId(hItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the node handle and then iterate over the elem
Iterate over all the elements, while you count the elements, till you reach the right item?

Comment: I was hoping to do it a bit more efficiently than that. My tree can be quite large.

Comment: If you're not using it already, put the index into the Tag field as you add items to the tree-structure (remembering to rebuild when you remove elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetIndex(const CString & a_Cstr)
{
    int idx = 0;
    std::vector<CString>::const_iterator _begIt = m_RulesVec.begin();
    std::vector<CString>::const_iterator _PosIt = find(m_RulesVec.begin(),      m_RulesVec.end(), a_Cstr);
    if (_PosIt == m_RulesVec.end()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        while (_begIt != _PosIt) {
            ++idx;
            ++_begIt;
        }
        return idx;
    }
}

/// it can(must) be done in this function
/// OnNMClickRulesTree(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)

    // Create vector like this
    std::vector<CString> Vec{"first", "second", "third" };

    // OnInit insert items to CtreeCtrl like this
    m_Tree.InsertItem("first", hItem);
    m_Tree.InsertItem("second", hItem);
    m_Tree.InsertItem("third", hItem);

    // then get cur selected item like this
    CPoint point;
    GetCursorPos(&point);
    m_Tree.ScreenToClient(&point);
    UINT nHitFlags;
    HTREEITEM hItem = m_Tree.HitTest(point, &nHitFlags);

    // get item text
    CString Cstr = m_Tree.GetItemText(hKid);
    int idx = GetIndex(Cstr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.